# How to change buttons' size of MessageDlg?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I managed to change font size of my MessageDlg using the following declaration:

```
function MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
                    Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Integer): Integer;
```

and the following implementation:

```
function MyForm.MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
                           Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Integer): Integer;
begin
  with CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons) do
    try
      Font.Size := 22;
      Result := ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end
end;
```

The problem is that the size of the buttons (and the size of the dialog) doesn't change according to the new font size.

Is there an easy way to adapt the size of the dialog buttons according to the font size I've set ?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: @HeartWare Delphi XE7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MessageDialog uses `Screen.MessageFont` for its message and size calculations.

Use

```
  Screen.MessageFont.Size := 22;
```

before you call `CreateMessageDialog`

You might want to store the old value and restore it after your message.